# How to stop my kids uncle from watching him mobile before bedtime

Tags: infant, behavior

My son is 1.5 years old, every evening or some night when his uncle takes him to his room, he put his mobile youtube videos and I believe it is affecting his sleep. I m a firm believer that watching a mobile screen at night may take your sleep away and make you active.

Is it true? I asked my wife many times to ask his brother not to do that but he won't listen and I m at the brink of busting my anger because my son is very reckless all night and gets scolded by his mom. What can I do? It is like my wife is too hesitate to ask his brother because she told he won't listen whereas I cannot see my wife struggling and scolding my son every night.

Comment: Why is the uncle in the bedroom while your baby's sleeping?

Comment: @OmarL He thinks the baby isn't looked after so he just come in to take the baby

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things going on here.

There is [reasonably firm evidence](https://www.uvpediatrics.com/topics/tv-may-be-causing-your-preschoolers-sleep-problems/) that TV immediately before bed time can cause sleep problems. However it may also depend on what is happening on the screen: if the videos are exciting and engaging then they are more likely to be an issue than if they are calm. So you might ask your brother in law what kind of videos he is showing.

Would he be willing to read a story instead? This is much more soothing than a video, and is more likely to send your son to sleep.

Finally, it sounds like your wife's scolding is likely to be counterproductive as well. Nothing is less likely to help a toddler relax than being scolded. If he keeps getting up or making a fuss then go in, calmly put him back to bed, give him a hug, and then leave. Do not make a fuss or turn up the stress: if you do then he won't understand, but he will be stressed and therefore even less likely to sleep than before.

Comment: The videos are cocomelon and d billions rythmes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the APA is clear; no screentime before 2.  (Zooming with relatives is different, because that's actually interactive)

It's not hard to google a huge number of reliable sources saying the same thing; TV before sleep is bad.  It's bad for people of all ages.

Your kid's uncle is a jerk, and if your wife would rather please him than do what's right for her children, your kids are going to suffer for it.

Comment: I'd upvote the first two paragraphs, but downvote the last one.  Leave personal judgements out of answers, and instead focus on what's important - answering the question.

Comment: This poster has multiple questions about how to work around his brother in law being a jerk.  There is a limit to what the OP can do when he's being sabotaged in his own household.

Comment: @swbarnes2 my problem is I cannot be straightforward and say it to the other reason, sometimes I really wish